# Left align piece-wise equation written with cases

Tags: amsmath, cases

I have a piece-wise function written with `numcases`, but it is aligned to the center.
I already have `fleqn` and `\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}` in the preamble. All the previous equations I have written are left aligned, except for this one.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,left=3cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm,top=2cm}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cases}{}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

 \begin{numcases}{f(x,y) =}
        x^2 + (y-k)^2 = k^2 &$; 0 < x < p$ \tag{4.3} \\ 
        (b_2-q)(x-a_2) + (p-a_2)(y-b_2) = 0 &$;x \geqslant \tag{4.4} p$  
     \end{numcases}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What could be the problem?
Please help.

Comment: This code doesn't use the `fleqn` option. Do you want all equations to be left-aligned?

Comment: Yes. I want all of them to be left aligned.
Isn't `\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}` using the `fleqn` option?

Comment: It works if you use it as an option of the document class.

Comment: What would have to be changed exactly then?

Comment: Write `\documentclass[11pt, fleqn]{article}`.